# calculate seo return on investment in actual dollor

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, google-search-console

is there any way to calculate SEO campaign investment in the actual dollar?

I had run some campaigns for generating content and content-backlink for one year and now I want to know the return on investment for my SEO activities